# Spring Cloud Config Server Not Refreshing

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I'm setting up a Spring cloud server to read of an internal Stash directory.

The server loads up ok the first time, but if I update properties in git, they don't get reflected until I restart cloud server (I try POST to /refresh endpoint).

I'm on Windows and I see a few bugs related to server on Windows but I don't see any specific mention of my bug.

Comment: Are you trying to POST to `/refresh` on a client?

Comment: Posted refresh to config server

Comment: OK, POST `/refresh` only makes sense on the client. Every call to `http://<configserverhost>:<configserverport>/<appname>/<label>` should make a new call to the git server.

Comment: Sure then probably some windows problem since that data was stale.

Comment: I take it back - I'm running now under same test with a project I downloaded using start.spring and I see the changes -- both linux and windows are updating fine. Have to track down what's the difference.

Comment: let me know if you find anything.

Answer (score 1):

see org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.RefreshEndpoint
code here：

```
public synchronized String[] refresh() {
    Map<String, Object> before = extract(context.getEnvironment()
            .getPropertySources());
    addConfigFilesToEnvironment();
    Set<String> keys = changes(before,
            extract(context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources())).keySet();
    scope.refreshAll();
    if (keys.isEmpty()) {
        return new String[0];
    }
    context.publishEvent(new EnvironmentChangeEvent(keys));
    return keys.toArray(new String[keys.size()]);
}
```

that means /refresh endpoint pull git first and then refresh catch,and public a environmentChangeEvent,so we can customer the code like this.